# Accessing the clients principal inside an ejb method

Tags: java, security, ejb-3.0

I need to access the clients principal (username ) inside a ejb method. I don't want to add it as a parameter. Tryed adding them to Context object like ;

```
prop.add(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"user")
prop.add(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"pass")
```

but trying to access them inside the method like;
    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

```
public void someMethod() {
    Principal principal = ctx.getCallerPrincipal();
    //returns anonymous
```

still give me the annoymous user.

Working on weblogic, any pointers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar issue...I am testing with a client cert along with a custom UserNameMapper.  My UserNameMapper returns "steve", but the principal within the EJB was returning `"<anonymous>"` until I added a "steve" user via the console.

```
Environment env = new Environment();
env.setInitialContextFactory(Environment.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
//  env.setSecurityPrincipal("user");
//  env.setSecurityCredentials("pass");
env.setProviderUrl("t3s://localhost:7002");

InputStream key = new PEMInputStream(new FileInputStream(CERT_KEYFILE));
InputStream cert = new PEMInputStream(new FileInputStream(CERT_CERTFILE));
env.setSSLClientCertificate(new InputStream[] {key, cert});
env.setSSLClientKeyPassword(CERT_KEYPASSWORD);
```

Same issue when using a JAAS client with the UsernamePasswordLoginModule.  Fixed by setting the username/password within the InitialContext lookup within the PrivilegedAction.  The EJB references the latter as the principal as it can be a different username/password.

Comment: Steve could you please explain this line, I will be really thankful to you `Fixed by setting the username/password within the InitialContext lookup within the PrivilegedAction`

Comment: See the example 17-3 http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/weblogic_chap17/index1.html?page=5.  There's an interesting bullet point that says not to provide the user credentials.  Been awhile now, but when I tested, I wasn't able to access the principal within the EJB without explicitly supplying them in the InitialContext.  So you would add something like the lines I commented out above into the example 17-3.  HTH

Comment: Thanks, I got it, It is WebLogic Specific code, Actually I was trying to access an EJB running on Glassfish from Standalone Application (from with in Eclipse). I have managed to authenticate client, but that information is not propagated to the EJB. It remains anonymous. Anyway thank you so much.